# iOS Simulators missing when deployment target set to 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm still new to Xcode, but I've recently run into an issue that has me stumped.  As best as I can tell, right after I updated to 10.10.3, and to Xcode 6.3, any new projects I create don't have an iOS Simulators available.  If I change the Deployment Target back to 8.2 (from 8.3), they are once again available.  But as long as I leave it set to a deployment target of 8.3, I can only see "iOS Device" and no iOS Simulators are listed.

I've tried deleting and reinstalling Xcode, but I'm still ending up with the same results.  Anyone else having this issue, and or know of a fix for this?

Comment: Every time I've upgraded Xcode, I've had to go re-download simulators. Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components.

Comment: Reinstalling the OS from the combo installer didn't help for me unfortunately.  However, I decided to try setting up a fresh user account to see if the problem was system-related or profile-related.  Turns out the new user worked like a charm, so I also trashed the ~/Library/Developer and well as the Xcode piece in the Caches, and when I relaunched Xcode, the simulators were back in action.  I'm not sure specifically where the issue lies, but it seems to be in one of those two folders in the home folder.

Comment: @kenleycapps Not that I've ever needed to do that step previously myself, as you say I did notice the option to download them in the Preferences in Xcode.  However, the only options in there were the older iOS simulators (8.2, 8.1, 7.1).  There's no 8.3 option.  That's why I kept digging.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue, and can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem as the original poster (Bill Matthews). On my MacPro (Early 09), but not my MacBookAir - both running 10.10.3 and newly installed Xcode 8.3 (over the beta 3 version) - I could not get any simulators to show up, irrespective of the iOS build target. (The temporary workaround was debugging on a real device, after selecting it from the "Product" menu -> "Destination"->"Ineligible Devices"->{my iPhone}.)

I tried deleting the simulators in ~/Library/Developer, but could not reinstall them; the Preferences->Downloads->Components would show them as installed/checked off, even after reboot, despite being deleted. Same result even after deleting the components folder and ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads and reboot. Same result even after deleting all of ~/Library/Developer, unlike Bill Matthews (Mazel Tov!).

In an abundance of caution, I reinstalled 10.10.3 from the combo updater (not AppStore), then Xcode 8.3 from developer.apple.com (not AppStore).

That did the trick for me.  YMMV.

Comment: Please post comments as comments, if you can't actually give an answer on how to fix the problem.

Comment: Please edit your post as a whole answer (ie: I reproduced the error on a MacPro [...] It wasn't fun, but I tried progressive [...]) or this could get deleted

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem. If you are using fastlane the easiest way is to use the following command.

```
fastlane snapshot reset_simulators
```

I was able to see the latest simulators afterwards.